# Dropdown template URI breaks on language switch

Tags: localization

I have the following code in my header of a multilingual site. It produces the correct urls in english.

```
{% for entry in menuentries %}

    {% if entry.entryLink.first|length %}
        {% set navlink = entry.entryLink.first().uri %}
    {% elseif entry.customMenuUrl|length %}
        {% set navlink = entry.customMenuUrl %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if entry.level == 1 and entry.children|length %}
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ navlink }}" class="dropdown-toggle {{ macros.activeLinkClass(entry.uri, entry.level)|trim }} level{{ entry.level }}" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-hover="dropdown" data-length="{{ entry.title|length }}aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ entry.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                {% for child in entry.getDescendants() %}
                    <li>
                        <a  href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ child.entryLink.first().uri  }}" class="{{ macros.isActiveChildClass(child.slug) | trim }} level{{ child.level }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>

    {% elseif entry.level == 1 and not entry.hasDescendants() %}

        <li>
            <a href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ navlink }}" class="{{ macros.activeLinkClass(entry.uri, entry.level) |trim }} level{{ entry.level }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        </li>

    {% endif %}
```

However when I switch languages eg. to french the `child.entryLink.first().uri` returns null. Even if I just change the `en` to `fr` I get the same result. Bit confused.

Comment: Are the entries selected in the `entryLink` field enabled for French?

Comment: I have checked field from menu "entryLink", and content entries - all are enabled and translatable.

Comment: @joomkit Can you add your update as an official answer?

Comment: I cant vote my own posts as answer...but happy to change - let me know what you need me to do

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
Mats you were right - I didnt have any data in the french menus or i had random custom url data. Once corrected the entry model came back whole. Phew